# Is it safe using more smaller ground wires instead of a bigger equivalent one?

Tags: power, current, ground, wire

I need to power up 4 resistive loads (at around 1A of current each, maximum), but the load provides only one returning ground capable of supporting 4A. I found that if I split this ground to 4 small wires, those can be put together with the other 4 supplies of each resistor, in one handy 8-pin connector.

In theory this split could work, since each of the 4 wires has more or less the same resistance, and so an average current of 1A can flow in each conductor.
But, is it safe in practice? Is there any lack of safety, or am I missing something else?

Thank you

Comment: Please draw a schematic.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem as long as the smaller wire is rated at 1A or better. It is even regarded as good practice for some applications as it gives better noise isolation between the loads.

Edit
There was some ambiguity in my original answer I was referring to the situation where one ground wire was used for each individual load.

Comment: He said an "average" of 1A... that implies that some wires may carry more, and need a higher rating.

Comment: @Eoin  From the question "I need to power up 4 resistive loads (at around 1A of current each, maximum)" . How is it possible to confuse maximum with average. Ok I see it later in the question. This is his assumption about what will happen and is inaccurate. The current through each ground return is the current for that load.

Comment: For the "average" I was referring to the fact that I am aware that we are not in ideal world and one cable may carry 1.1A and the other 0.9 and so on (but anyway a negligible variation), due to tolerances on the wire itself. For the "maximum" is that the worst case (so the only one to be considered) is that the 4 loads will carry 1A each.

Comment: @royc that is the key of the question: the minimum wire capability, and what to consider to calculate it.

Comment: @RoyC - It becomes a problem when one of the connections goes bad and then current is only shared across 3 wires. One conductor is always better.

Comment: @thexeno Yes I know that if you are supplying each of these loads with 1A  then each ground return will be only carrying 1A. Size your wires accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

From the phrasing of your question it's difficult to know exactly what you mean. You state that you are powering '4 resistive loads' and then say that 'the load...' (note the use of the singular) '...only provides only one returning ground capable of supporting 4A'.  So should the reader assume that 4 power feeds of 1A into 4 loads with their grounds joined to a single (4A) cable: the only access to the circuit are the 5 wires (4 feeds and single earth)?  If that is so: connecting the 4A cable to 4 1A cables will not guarantee an even division of current among the 4 1A cables.  Kirchoffs current law states that the sum of currents flowing into a point (the join between the 4A cable and the 4 x 1A cables is the same as the sum of currents flowing out of the point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_current_law_.28KCL.29

However there is nothing that says the current flowing in is evenly distributed between the cables conducting current away.  We (should) know that current depends on ohms law ( C = V/R ).  If you consider that there is no such thing as a truly zero ohm circuit then unless each of your 4 1A wires and their associated joints and connections are *perfectly* equal then you can conclude that the currents will not be equal. As we don't know the source voltage you are dealing with it's not possible to calculate what the current variation might be between the wires for a given resistance difference.  However it's almost certain that the majority of current will try to flow down the wire with the lowest in circuit resistance and far exceed it's rating.  (causing the wire to burn out) So, No not a safe idea. However if you want to try it then fuse each 1A wire individually with slo-blow fuses.  You'll find that they will all fail.

Comment: Read the question. Each load is 1A maximum.

Comment: Yes, as I explained there is some ambiguity in the question, and I explained the assumption on which the remainder of my response was based.  TL:DR - splitting a conductor carrying 4A into 4 conductors capable of 1A each will not guarantee an even division of current between the 4 cables.

Answer (score -2):

This can be a problem not so much with the wires as with the connector.  It's common for the contact resistance to be not only greater than the wire resistance, but also with more pin-to-pin variability - especially after a few mate cycles or in a less-than-pristine environment. This turns the connector into a current divider, with some pins taking significantly more current than others.

Adding low-value (e.g. 1 ohm) "ballast" resistors in series with each wire is an easy, if lossy, way to balance the currents.